# Retag HTTP verbs

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Can we retag [get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/get) and [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/post) to [http-get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-get) and [http-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-post) (and the same for the others)?

The tag wikis don't help at all.

I think these words are well overloaded.

- [get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/get) (~6,000) -> [http-get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-get) (~600)
- [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/post) (~16,000) -> [http-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-post) (~3000)
- [head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/head) (~400) -> [http-head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-head) (~14)
- <s>[delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delete) (~7000)</s> -> [http-delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-delete) (~33)
- [put](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/put) (~600) -> [http-put](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-put) (~100)
- <s>[options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/options) (~1000)</s> -> [http-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-options) (0)

I know this is a big operation, but I think we ought to provide guidance and eliminate the duplication.

Aside: the HTTP status codes are tagged similarly and uniformly: [http-status-code-200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-200)

---

Related

- [Should we [delete] [deletion] and [deleting]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298476)
- [The [options] tag has been burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417320)

Comment: Are they? I can not find that much occasions where they would not mean the http method.

Comment: For get, what about an accessor? Posting can be used in the context of messaging systems (it can even be used as a noun), PUT, without HTTP is a bit strange, then there is http's DELETE, which is quite easily mistaken for something else. @PlasmaHH

Comment: @11684: I think this is exactly why tags should not stand on their own. There are lots of single word tags out there that are somewhat ambiguous on their own, but adding a http/web related tag will make them clear. I think the important point is how people use the tags, and I find that most get and post tags are more or less properly used with the http related meaning.

Comment: @PlasmaHH a problem is that there's duplication

Comment: @DanielA.White: where do we want to stop? http-post-json-rpc when we want to talk about an rpc protocol that uses json data in http post requests? How do we tag if we particularily want to talk about https? I think tags should be seen together as a whole, building up on each other.

Comment: @PlasmaHH i do agree with you that tags can be combined to have a new meaning. i'm just trying to propose eliminating the duplication and ambiguity of these common English words.

Comment: Another related tag: [tag:http-options-method]