# Make [http-error] and [http-status] synonyms of [http-status-codes]

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

Both [http-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-error) (192 questions) and [http-status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status) (21 questions) mean essentially the same thing (though [http-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-error) is a subset of [http-status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status)).  There's also [http-status-codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-codes) (669 questions).  I think it would make the most sense to make both [http-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-error) and  [http-status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status) synonyms of [http-status-codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-codes).  This would also fit with the existing format that [http-status-code-200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-200), [http-status-code-404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-404), [http-status-code-400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-400), ect. use.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262349/retag-http-verbs