# Clean up the HTTP status codes

Tags: discussion, retag-request, burninate-request

I was looking around (again) and noticed that there are tags for the HTTP status codes. Many of these tags only have a few questions, but some of the main ones (301, 304, 404, 500, etc.) have hundreds of questions, all with the common tie of "this doesn't work, here's the error code".

The [http-status-code-500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-500) excerpt says

> Please DO NOT USE THIS TAG. It is meaningless for categorizing your question.

Which I think sums up most of these tags, and is the reason behind making this request: **They're meaningless for categorizing the questions.**

---

**Most of the heavily-used status codes (404, 500, etc) contain very general questions**, typically involving services or scripts which return the status code. These questions almost always have a common tie of "this doesn't work, help me fix it", which goes against the point of tags.

> [Tags are meant to group questions into specific, well-defined categories](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). Giving something a [http-status-code-404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-404) tag because "it says it can't be found" is about as meaningful as giving something a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) tag because it "just stopped working".

- [Jquery ajaxrequest xhr.status code 0 but html status code 200](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8832359/359284)
- [Htaccess 301 redirect one url to another with special characters doesnt work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21940674/359284)
- [Upgrade to ASP.NET MVC 5 Error 403.14 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24343788/359284)
- [laravel 4 all routes except home result in 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13514990/359284)
- [ASP.NET MVC / IIS 7.5: 500 Internal Server Error for static content only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13677458/359284)

**Many of the less-used status codes (205, 308, [418](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2324#section-2.3.2), etc) fit better under [http-status-codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-codes)** as the questions are general geared towards implementation questions about when the status codes should be used, and what is required to use them.

- [What's the purpose of the HTTP status 205 Reset Content?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26803855/359284)
- [Can I use HTTP response 424 when a request requires another request to be done first?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27286857/359284)
- [HTTP Status Code for Captcha](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26547466/359284)
- [What's the deal with HTTP status code 308?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14144664/359284)
- [HTTP Status 412 (Precondition Failed) and Database Versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3620203/359284)

**So I propose the tags are burninated, retagging questions where it is appropriate to [http-status-codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-codes).**

---

**Related retag requests**

- [Make [http-error] and [http-status] synonyms of [http-status-codes]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276515/359284)
- [Retag http verbs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262349/359284)

Comment: I think the bigger cleanup effort should be finding and cataloging all of those tag excerpts that say, "DO NOT USE", since that's *clearly* not doing a damn thing to prevent their usage.

Comment: More to the point, why shouldn't we keep (some) of them around?  It more or less gives a narrower scope to the actual issues at hand, and they may not *always* be related to a framework.

Comment: @Makoto Tags are meant to [group questions into specific, well-defined categories](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). Giving something a [http-status-code-404] tag because "it says it can't be found" is about as meaningful as giving something a [bug] tag because it "just stopped working". There _might_ be some tags worth saving, I encourage you (and others) to point them out if they exist.

Comment: I did say *some* of them.  Yes, there are those that just don't need to be around (I'd say 200, most of the 3XX class, 404, and 500), but there are others which could serve a purpose.  I think these need to be looked at on a case-by-case basis rather than a blanket burn-'em-all.

Comment: I've reworked the initial post as I do agree that some of these tags shouldn't be completely burned without considering the question, but instead should be merged as [tag:http-status-codes] because they are referencing the codes themselves, and not the cause for them being triggered.

Comment: You're almost certainly correct about some of these but you haven't actually provided an argument for removing all of them. If they have their own tag then people can find them quicker. How does hiding questions under thousands of others help? Why not burninate [tag:http-status-codes] for being too generic rather than the tags themselves?

Comment: @Ben I didn't suggest burninating that tag because I do see _some value_ in keeping the general tag around for things like [implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13637083/359284) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14484473/359284), as they're pretty different (and more fitting for a tag) than [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27863946/359284) [about](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27352721/359284) [why](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26894320/359284) [the](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27798510/359284) [error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27824651/359284) itself is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general list of tags where most questions should not be re-tagged, and most questions should be re-tagged. Feel free to make a comment if you disagree with a specific tag.

**Keep in mind that each question should be considered individually**, there are some pearls hidden in these tags and it doesn't make sense to re-tag one bad question just because all of the other good ones are being re-tagged.

**Burninate**

Most of the questions under these tags are about a specific error involving the status code, and not the implementation of the status code itself. Some questions should be retagged though, **so use your best judgement when reviewing questions** before you remove the tag.

[http-status-code-200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-200) (24)

[http-status-code-301](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-301) (1021) [http-status-code-302](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-302) (312) [http-status-code-304](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-304) (93)

[http-status-code-400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-400) (199) [http-status-code-401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-401) (380) [http-status-code-403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-403) (685) [http-status-code-404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-404) (3083) [http-status-code-405](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-405) (166)

[http-status-code-500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-500) (825) [http-status-code-503](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-503) (161) [http-status-code-504](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-504) (52)

**Retag as [http-status-codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-codes)**

Many of the questions in these tags are about implementing the status codes themselves, instead of debugging errors which trigger them. These are more on-topic for [http-status-codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-codes) and should be retagged. Of course, if there is a question which does not fit [http-status-codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-codes), **do not re-tag it but instead just remove the old tag**.

[http-status-code-100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-100) (16)

<del>[http-status-code-201](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-201) (6)</del> [http-status-code-204](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-204) (7) [http-status-code-205](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-205) (1)

[http-status-code-303](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-303) (18) [http-status-code-307](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-307) (21) [http-status-code-308](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-308) (2)

[http-status-code-406](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-406) (64) [http-status-code-407](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-407) (21) [http-status-code-408](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-408) (8) [http-status-code-409](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-409) (1) [http-status-code-410](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-410) (36) [http-status-code-411](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-411) (10) [http-status-code-412](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-412) (9) [http-status-code-413](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-413) (20) [http-status-code-415](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-415) (27) [http-status-code-424](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-424) (1)

[http-status-code-505](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-505) (9)

*Please update this answer as tags are burninated by crossing them out with `<del></del>`.*

Comment: I've reviewed and re-tagged the [tag:http-status-code-201] questions; they are awaiting peer review.