# Standardise! No more [custom-error-pages]!

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

Looks to me like the [custom-error-pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-error-pages) tag is pretty superfluous. It doesn't really describe any particular technology, how to make "custom error pages" is completely different depending on what context you're talking about, and hence I have a hard time seeing how this tag would benefit anyone. Even its wiki is empty. Let's burninate!?

Comment: Your request is [noted](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/25123548#25123548) and I assume our room will help...

Comment: what should we have instead? Are you suggesting we should have technology specific custom error page tags? Because I'm not sure if that's good either.

Comment: @eis How about *nothing*? "Custom error pages" are always coupled with something else: Apache, .NET, AwesomeFrameworkOfTheWeek2.0, whatever. Those tags should be enough IMO.

Comment: Using the same logic, there's also [custom-error-handling] and especially [error-handling], which seem to be even more dependant on the context. However, when combined with a technology/language tag they start having real meaning, just like custom-error-pages. Removing all those would leave the questions quite bare. (However, like I said, I am really unsure what would be the best approach. I guess I'm just thinking aloud here.)

Comment: Also thinking out loud: [tag:custom-error-pages] or [tag:custom-error-handling] seems *too specific* and at the same time *too wishy-washy* to be of much use. "Too wishy-washy" because, as mentioned, by itself it doesn't mean anything. While when paired with another tag, it seems to be overly specific to be really useful as a category. *"I'm using C# and I'm interested in implementing a custom error handler"* – that as a question title should be fine. Will anyone really ever search for this topic as tag? I'm doubtful.

Comment: Brief Google search suggests that custom error pages would most commonly refer to custom "404 not found" web pages. So I suppose the tag http-status-code-404 is better to use for such questions.

Comment: @Lundin again, how you implement those are dependent of something else, which could be webserver, application, language, etc. That context should be on the title/body of the question, is not useful as tag categorization, unless somehow we get a http-status-code-404 course when studying something else...

Comment: @Lundin: I disagree. You can have 500 error pages or assorted other status codes. Rather than giving each one its own tag, it seems reasonable to lump them together. I expect that the mechanism for each error page is similar, except for the code itself.

Comment: @Lundin [Others would disagree](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283903/359284) about the usefulness of tags for HTTP status codes.

Comment: Looks like most "custom-error-pages" question talk about web sites and it is quite common term for web development. I think the term itself is reasonably well defined (never seen it mentioned outside web context), but indeed can't stand as only tag on the questions. I think in current state questions are tagged reasonably - so from my point of view burination of the tag should be done only if it violates some policy about tags.

Comment: To me it certainly seems reasonable for someone wanting to read about how custom error pages are implemented in <some web platform> (or quirks related to said implementation) to search for [some-web-platform] + [custom-error-pages]. I don't think "custom error pages" is really an overly specific topic.

Answer (score 5):

The tag has 90% .NET questions. Surely, what this tag mostly means is [ASP.NET custom errors](https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en&gws_rd=ssl#complete=1&hl=en&q=ASP.NET%20custom%20errors). "Custom errors" is the official name of the feature. The tag appears to be misnamed.

I think the questions should be split into two groups:

1. .NET questions should have the tag replaced by [custom-errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-errors).
2. All other questions should have the tag removed.
3. [custom-errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-errors) should be renamed `asp.net-custom-errors`.

The tag should be banned because it is too unspecific.

Comment: Having a tag named [custom-errors] is just asking for disambiguation later, solve the problem and look for a more specific term.

Comment: @Braiam I agree, I forgot to say something about that.