# Stop protecting [protect]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

Currently, [209 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protect) are tagged [protect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protect). It is mainly used as a synonym for "prevent" or "hide".

This is a meta tag and I do not see any value in having it. Questions tagged with it range from [security concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29636366/1743880) to [data validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29619670/1743880) and even [obfuscation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/194397/1743880).

There is only one follower and it's wiki is currently empty.

I think this tag can safely be burned : it doesn't add any information to the post and it is clearly ambiguous.

Comment: Stop protecting [protect]

Comment: Also, detect retagged [protect].

Comment: Burn that [protect]ion!

Comment: Nothing can [protect] you now!

Comment: Stop the [meming]!

Comment: We have [tag:security] and [tag:obfuscation] tags, but what the hell is [tag:data-validation] (no wiki) and how is it different from [tag:validation]?

Comment: While at it, why not also burn [tag:protection]?

Comment: I think it is safe to say that when a word root is burninated all of it's variants are also

Comment: well yes but [protected] may still be valid

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot can you give an example?

Comment: @Sammaye `protected` is a keyword in C-ish languages which describes a type of inheritance. You might argue that questions about that should just be tagged with the appropriate language along with [inheritance] or similar, but inquisitiveIdiot *did* say "*may* still be valid"

Comment: @SeldomNeedy We have a tag for the [tag:protected] keyword.

Comment: @ArtjomB. here, I created something about data-validation and validation. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302765/whats-with-the-tags-data-validation-and-validation

Comment: I think Tuanki is trying to tell us to stop using protection.

Comment: @SeldomNeedy isn't that kind of detail normally considered bad for tagging? Not to mention that it's use would be vague since the question list will be polluted with people randomly using the tag

Comment: @Sammaye it depends on quite how polluted. You're probably right that it isn't *that* helpful of a tag, really, although I wouldn't put it on the same level as [protect] in terms of burnination-deservedness.

Comment: @SeldomNeedy maybe, the biggest problem I see is that protected is a keyword (also in inheritance) in almost every language I have used, from PHP to python to C# to C++. But I see your point

Comment: @Sammaye Sure, but the meaning of the keyword isn't uniform across those languages! Knowing how `protected` works in C++ won't help you answer a question about how it works in PHP, for instance.

Comment: @duskwuff doesnt that then render the tag even  more useless?

Comment: Maybe you're all just being a little too overprotective?

Comment: If you have a question about [tag:php] and [tag:protected], and you search using [those tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=newest&tags=php%20protected&mode=all), you get a list of questions pertaining to php's protected construct. If you then narrow your search using other search terms, it is very easy to find more specifically related questions. Same thing with C, or any other language that has that construct.

Comment: See also: [What is the point of generic, language-agnostic tags about basic programming concepts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300571/what-is-the-point-of-generic-language-agnostic-tags-about-basic-programming-con)

Comment: However, [tag:protect] should burn in hell, possibly even [tag:protection]

Comment: @TinyGiant when would you search by those two tags, as an asker you would search for keywords only, as an answerer you would search by PHP only. It is like the burnination request recently: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302652/standardise-no-more-custom-error-pages

Comment: Uhm.... no. If I'm going to ask a question, I use all of the resources available. Why should askers not use tags when searching? That just seems daft. @Sammaye

Comment: Tags are for better classifying questions. If I have a question about a language concept of a specific language, I should be able to tag the question with the language and the concept. Plain and simple. [tag:protected] should *not* be removed.

Comment: @TinyGiant Askers would not use tags since protected is too much detail. A person would search in the PHP tag for something about protected, not all protected questions. A tag applies to all questions tagged

Comment: @TinyGiant Why don't you come up with a case where tagging with protected genuinely helps clarify beyond adding it to the title?

Comment: @TinyGiant of course, the other problem here is that the protected tag being too mcuh detail is not one that will be used by standard unlike other tags, as such searching by it is near useless anyway since it will not give the results of all questions about the protected paradigm in OOP

Comment: If I'm asking a question ***about the protected concept of PHP*** then I would use the php tag and the protected tag. Why shouldn't I be able to use a tag for the thing that my post is most about? And if you actually go to the link I posted earlier, you will see a lot of questions ***about the protected concept of PHP***. I can then filter those questions down further. But, if I search for all questions with the word "protected" in the body, I'm going to find a whole lot of unrelated questions that just happen to mention that word.

Comment: Tags are not just for answerers to easily find questions, but actually mostly for users looking for an answer to their question that has already been asked. If you remove ways to easily classify relevant questions, you end up with more duplicates. Also, google gives a different weight to the tags as opposed to the words in the question.

Comment: @TinyGiant you must remember that the associated questions/answers that is shown to the user works on more than just tags. It works based on content, title and tags. If it worked on tags only then it would not be very effective. As to the Google weighting: have you got any proof? I decided to search the tag listed in the content: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=meta%20so%20protect and couldn't find this question that well, in fact the questions are not tagged protect at all.

Comment: I think you misunderstand, protect is not a language construct, and it is ambiguous. Protected on the other hand is useful and not ambiguous. And do you really think that people looking for information don't use the search feature at all? Seriously? That's what the search feature is there for. I so far have not read a reason why protected should be removed. It is unambiguous and helps classify the question, leave it alone. Otherwise all of the loop tags, and any other language construct tag would qualify for burnination, and that is just wrong. @Sammaye

Comment: @TinyGiant but you said that tags are weighted in Google, as such the tag displayed in this article should be weighted (I am something of a SEO expert after all the Google tweaking I have had to do and have never heard this, hell I even had to talk to the Google search team themselves at one point). Despite my example not being the one you mention it should work, in fact here you go: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=stackoverflow+protected

Comment: @TinyGiant I have already explained my logic behind the searching of these questions and my logic behind the uselessness of the tag

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=stackoverflow%20protected&rct=j#q=site:stackoverflow.com+php+protected+member @Sammaye

Comment: @TinyGiant that is too narrow a search, that catches on too many titles and content

Comment: @TinyGiant plus the questions there are not tagged "protected" if you browse them, i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745394/php-inheritance-and-protected-member-visibility

Comment: It provides useful search results and the first result is the tag page itself, if I'm searching, thats how I search. If the tag is gone, a lot of those questions wouldn't be listed in that search.

Comment: Then they should be and they are mistagged. Just because a tag is not used correctly does not mean it should be burninated.

Comment: @TinyGiant I am unsure what search result you see but the first result for me is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745394/php-inheritance-and-protected-member-visibility

Comment: That is the second on my results sammaye, it helps classify questions. If it helps classify the question and is not ambiguous, it should be left alone. @Sammaye

Comment: @TinyGiant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361553/php-public-private-protected is not the tag page, and it matches due to the content, if the tag was weighted it would come above the first result

Comment: @Sammaye I know that, for some reason on my list of results the actual tag page is the first result. I'm done arguing. It's a good tag.

Comment: The tag is now gone. We can safely mark this [status-completed].

Comment: @BhargavRao Or we could extend it to [tag:protection]

Comment: @ArtjomB. Yes. The day I saw your comment up there I went through the list of questions with that tag. It does validate burnination, but I do not know if that comes under the scope of this question. Apart from that a few questions are of real bad quality and hence require closure and not just re-tagging. In any case the title of the new question (if asked) would be *Stop using [protection]*

Comment: @ArtjomB. I have gone ahead and started to cv [protection] questions as well. But IMHO a new meta-post would be better.

Comment: @BhargavRao This post already exists: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296710

Comment: @Tunaki thanks for that. It is funny that my comment is the first there and I have forgotten the post! :D

Comment: @Tunaki In that case please do a self-answer here and accept it. You can add a link to the other "retag-request".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to the community at large, the tag [protect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protect) is now

## ***BURNINATED***

[image]

As evoked in the [comments above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302679/stop-protecting-protect?noredirect=1#comment239522_302679), there is a retag-request for the similar [protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protection). There is another question pertaining to it's burnination [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296710).