# What's with the tags data-validation and validation?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

So, there's a tag for [validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/validation), which has some wiki content on it, and some nice questions and answers.

But there's also the [data-validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-validation) tag... And has no wiki on it.

Can we merge then, and burn data-validation? Or is there a difference I am not perceiving from data-validation?

EDIT: By the comments, it seems better we add data-validation as a Synonym to validation. It seems the best way to deal with these both tags.

Comment: Probably better as a [meta-tag:synonym-request]

Comment: Or a [meta-tag:clean-up] request, if [tag:data-validation] is really that bad.

Comment: I don't know, I have no idea on what's the default procedure?

Comment: Also, data-validation have close to only 300. Could we clean then, convert then to validation and delete the tag?

Comment: You really don't want to retag more than 300 questions in [data-validation] if it's a synonym. Note that retagging is not simply exchanging the tags. You would also need to check if the question should be closed and if not, fix all the other things that are wrong with it with a single edit.

Comment: Can we make it as a Synonym-request, then block creation of new questions with that tag?

Comment: Tag black-listing is done very rarely and only for zombie tags that come back frequently from the dead. If it's synonymized, then it can't be used again, because new questions will be automatically rewritten to use the parent tag. Only if you burn the tag, it may come back.

Comment: @ArtjomB. thanks for the nice explanation. I edited it.

Comment: Why not burninate the [tag:validation] tag? What purpose does it serve? How is categorizing questions by whether or not they “validate” “something” helpful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This makes sense given the content of posts with [data-validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-validation) and the existing syn's of [form-validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/form-validation) and [input-validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/input-validation).

So, [data-validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-validation) -> [validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/validation) is syn'd and merged.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a problem data-validation having so many synonyms?

Comment: @Malavos it's `validation` that has [alternate names](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/validation/synonyms)... it's not a problem...

Comment: @Deduplicator I would. Can you create it, if it's a problem?