# Synonymize [404-page] to [http-status-code-404]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

Both [404-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/404-page) and [http-status-code-404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-404) refer to the same thing, where a specific path is not found. The former page is a result of the latter status code. I don't think that difference warrants a separate tag. Propose synonymizing [404-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/404-page) to [http-status-code-404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-404)

Comment: I don't think it's the same. Status code 404 (not sure why there's a tag for this, seems specific) is about the response code, 404-page is supposedly about a webpage. Way back 20 years ago when I actually did web development, I remember there being ways to configure default error pages in apache and nginx which is what I would suppose the `404-page` tag would be appropriate for (and the `http-status-code-404` would not be.)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas In that case we would need tag usage to be cleared in the respective tag wikis. As of now 404-page has no tag wiki. I suppose you may say that the 404 tag wiki was not found :)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I did partially cover that difference in the post itself - my opinion is that it doesn't warrant a separate tag.

Comment: I agree with @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: 404-page makes at least some sense as an item, http-status-code-404 seems a bit excessive and perhaps all of the codes could fall under http-status-code? I don't think there's any scenario where someone is proficient at 404s but not 200s/300s to really warrant the distinction.

Comment: @TheMaster My point was they're distinct concepts which make sense as distinct tags and they should _not_ be synonyms. My secondary point was that `http-status-code-404` probably shouldn't exist at all as it is too specific (prefer a generic `http-status-code` tag for that one.)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas `http-status-code-*`s  is  very helpful in categorizing API request/client errors. If I get 404 in say, [google-sheets-api], I would just search  `[google-sheets-api][http-status-code-404]`. If I get 403, I would search  ``[google-sheets-api][http-status-code-403]``, the status codes have very specific reasons, even more specific, when combined with a api,  and really helps in narrowing down the issues.

Comment: I disagree with the premise. A "404" web ***page*** is not equivalent to a HTTP 404 ***status code***. It's true, a 404 status code *could* result in a 404 page being used, but one doesn't necessitate other. They are too dissimilar to synonymize. If anything the `http-status-code-404` is ***too*** specific and probably deserves an action on its own, like being synonymized into a general `http-status-code` tag.

Comment: The vast majority of [tag:404-page] posts have something about an actual page https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B404-page%5D+page Arguably the remaining ones should be retagged

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I think that's a fair point. It's possible you need to return a 404 status code and not necessarily an "error page". To that end, I suspect we should clean this tag up and then synonym [404-page] to [custom-error-pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-error-pages) (which is a clearer concept tagwise)

Comment: To the close voters: disagreement should be expressed with downvotes, not with close votes.

Comment: @DrewReese Merging all the status codes [was proposed 8 years ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283903/241211).

Comment: @Michael Before my time, but thanks. I've upvoted that post. Perhaps it can be revived.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a case to be made here that a 404 **status** and a 404 **page** are not the same thing. An API, for instance, might just return a 404 status without any other data at all.

That said, I still don't like the tag. I think the more generic [custom-error-pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-error-pages) tag might be the ticket here. Clean the tag up and synonym it to that tag instead

Comment: Tags merged and synonym created