# Tag consolidation: post > http-post, and get > http-get

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

I would like to propose synonymizing [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/post) to [http-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-post). They both have almost the same description; and [http-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-post) already has [post-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/post-request) as a synonym.

Similarly, [get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/get) should be a synonym for [http-get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-get) to reduce the ambiguity of the former.

Comment: What about https or SPDY? These are generic and should remain as is.

Comment: I never mentioned these in my post ... so not sure why you are commenting about those. My request is specifically for [tag:get] and [tag:post].

Comment: I am saying that [tag:get] and [tag:post] are generic enough to be used for other protocols, even if the wiki description disagrees with that.

Comment: In that case, the question can be tagged in addition to `http-get` or `http-post`; just `get` or `post` by itself is too generic. These tags (in their tag description) specifically mention HTTP.

Comment: I think that both should just be burned, not synonymized.

Comment: There’s also [tag:put] and [tag:http-put].

Comment: There is also [tag:get-request] which has no wiki and contains basically only questions about HTTP GET

Comment: related [Retag HTTP verbs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262349/1595451)