# On the road to the disambiguation of [post] (Vs [http-post] & Vs [posts])

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

There are several old posts asking to do things with [post], [http-post] and other related tags, like:

- [Retag HTTP verbs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262349/1595451)
- [Tag consolidation: post > http-post, and get > http-get](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296883/1595451)

One of the "problems" between [post] and [http-post] is that both tags have the very similar tag excerpts, saying that theses tags should be used for questions about HTTP POST requests.

Another problem is that there are many questions about blog posts, forum posts, etc tagged with [post] instead of [posts].

As the "post" word has many uses in English as well in programming, I'm wondering if besides the use of [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/post) for questions about WordPress (or other blogs) posts, what other topics could be tagged with this tag?

---

- [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/post) has 40,362 questions
- [http-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-post) has 8,556 questions
- [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/posts) has 961 questions
- [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/article) has 374 questions
- [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/posting) has 156 questions
- [blog-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blog-post) has 13 questions

---

While I was thinking about a disambiguation proposal I crafted the following search

[[post] -[javascript] -[php] -[curl] -[json] -[python] -[postman] -http -[jquery] -[google-*]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=9&tab=Relevance&q=%5Bpost%5D%20-%5Bjavascript%5D%20-%5Bphp%5D%20-%5Bcurl%5D%20-%5Bjson%5D%20-%5Bpython%5D%20-%5Bpostman%5D%20-http%20-%5Bjquery%5D%20-%5Bgoogle-*%5D) and scanning through the search results found several posts having

- [wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) and [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/post) and from the title and post excerpt its clear that the question is about a WordPress (blog) post, meaning that tag apparently doesn't match the question content.

---

- [[wordpress] [post]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress+post) 1,364 questions
- [[facebook] [post]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook+post) 451 questions
- [[blogs] [post] -[wordpress]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blogs+post+-wordpress) 52 questions
- [[blogger] [post]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blogger+post) 46 questions
- [[feed] [post]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feed+post) 33 questions
- [[tumblr] [post]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tumblr+post) 31 questions

---

"pure" [sql] + [post]

- [[sql][post] -[javascript] -[php] -[curl] -[json] -[python] -[postman] -http -[jquery] -[google-*] a](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql%5D%5Bpost%5D%20-%5Bjavascript%5D%20-%5Bphp%5D%20-%5Bcurl%5D%20-%5Bjson%5D%20-%5Bpython%5D%20-%5Bpostman%5D%20-http%20-%5Bjquery%5D%20-%5Bgoogle-*%5D) 89 questions

  - [Select all post and its comments for a specific user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26265470/1595451)
    This questions use the term "post" to refer to table records. It doesn't mentions the content management system used / type of "post" (user created content).

---

[post] has being used on questions about

- entries (at conceptual level / end-user point of view) on a blog, discussion forum, or other content management systems
- records (data entry ) on a database table that stores the content of a blog (see above)
- HTTP POST requests

Related

- [Clean up of run-together/hyphenated and singular/plural tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251478/1595451)
- [Time to refile the [form]s](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381405/1595451)
- [Have you read my [article] about burnination?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397465/1595451)

Comment: There's also [sitemap], [rss], and [atom-feed] (only a couple tagged both though, I doubt they're common in the rest). Anything involving blogs is probably in the same category. Seeing some questions about what appears to be self-made blog solutions, so I imagine there's a bunch of those, as well as questions about systems similar to wordpress (though I'm blanking on examples right now)

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine Thank you. Those tags combined with [post] returned very few questions (less than 10) but  [feed] + [post] returned few more (adde the count to question)

Comment: "*This questions use the term "post" to refer to table records*" - no it doesn't. It uses the term in the same meaning as a blog does - things that were posted by a user. Also the other SQL questions that you linked use "post" either in the blogpost or http-post sense. All of them should be retagged.

Comment: I see the utility of `http-post` as a tag, but what's the use of `post`? It seems like a meta tag to me.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas even the ambiguity that could be argued that `post` might have apparently most of the questions (~37K/40k) having this tag are some way related to http post requests... after a clean-up it might be made a synonym of `http-post`.

Comment: I think that [tag:http-post] is the only useful tag here. [tag:blog-post] is a meta tag, and and [tag:post], [tag:posts] and [tag:posting] are ambiguous. I think we should burninate these four tags and retag to [tag:http-post] where appropriate. [tag:article] might be useful when referring to the HTML `<article>` tag, but it's currently has other uses as well, so if we're going to keep it it should probably be renamed to something less ambiguous.